# How can I access a collection of acts_as_state_machine states for a particular rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, aasm

Is it possible to access the collection of states for the given model:

class Conversation
    include AASM

```
aasm_initial_state :unread

aasm_state :unread
aasm_state :read
aasm_state :closed

aasm_event :view do
  transitions :to => :read, :from => [:unread]
end

aasm_event :close do
  transitions :to => :closed, :from => [:read, :unread]
end
```

end

I would like to be able to get an array of states like:

```
['unread', 'read', 'closed']
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AASM gem has two class methods that return a collection of states for a given model:

```
  aasm_states
  aasm_states_for_select
```

For instance:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  aasm_initial_state :unread

  aasm_state :unread
  aasm_state :read
  aasm_state :closed

  aasm_event :view do
    transitions :to => :read, :from => [:unread]
  end

  aasm_event :close do
    transitions :to => :closed, :from => [:read, :unread]
  end 
end

> Note.aasm_states
> Note.aasm_states_for_select
```